# visual code gives winpty error and won't open at all

Tags: winpty

visual code gives two types of errors and does not open in both.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQtwS.png)

Sometimes the error number 259 appears on the screen, sometimes it gives the winpty error and prevents the terminal from opening. How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Remove and then reinstall VS Code. Does the error remain?

Comment: yes i tried that too but it didn't fix the problem